# Flutter application not launching on Android device

Tags: android, flutter, pixel, samsung

I have a flutter app but it is not launching on an specific device. I have 2 testing devices: Pixel 4 (Android 12) and Samsung SM G973U (Android 12), but the app it is not launching on the Pixel, it is being installed but the app does not launch when I run it from Android Studio. It gets stuck in this and never launches

> Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 4 in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
> ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.

The thing is that I do not change anything, I connect the Samsung device and run the app and it launches in the Samsung phone. I checked the developer options in both devices and they have the same options.

I even tried `flutter clean`, uninstalling the app in the Pixel, resetting to factory the Pixel, and still not launching the app. I need to open it manually then I can see the logs in the Run tab in Android Studio.

Any idea how to fix this? It is frustrating that I need to open the app manually to see my changes.

Comment: Are there any more logs you can share? 
The `Warning: Mapping new ns` snippet you shared is just a warning. That is not causing the issue in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the warning is not causing the issue. I have seen that before and even in the Samsung device it is printed, and the Samsung is launching the app. My point is that after the ‘Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.’ the app is not launching in my Pixel and no more logs are printed.